# jquery : how to build multiple lightbox with the same jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How can we make universal light box i mean same code for all light box function in the page 
here is JQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.lightbox').click(function() {
            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
                'opacity': '.50'
            }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.box').animate({
                'opacity': '1.00'
            }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
        });

        $('.close').click(function() {
            close_box();
        });

        $('.backdrop').click(function() {
            close_box();
        });

    });

    function close_box() {
        $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
            'opacity': '0'
        }, 300, 'linear', function() {
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
        });

}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/nBYvH/3/)**

Comment: Apply same classes "lightbox" and other css classes, whereever you use.

Comment: @SivaCharan take a look the demo http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/nBYvH/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script doesn't know which lightbox to pull up because you never specify one.  One way that you can set the lightbox is to designate the lightbox `id` in one of the `<a>` attributes.  Then, on click, pull the value of that attribute and reference with `$("#valuePulledFromAttribute")` rather than the generic `$('.backdrop, .box')` you are using now.

I was able to create a fork using no HTML5: http://jsfiddle.net/J6ee5/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.lightbox').click(function() {
    var thisBox = $(this).attr("name");
    console.log(thisBox);
    $('.backdrop,.' + thisBox).animate({
        'opacity': '.50'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $('.box').animate({
        'opacity': '1.00'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $('.backdrop,.' + thisBox).css('display', 'block');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
    close_box();
});

$('.backdrop').click(function() {
    close_box();
});

function close_box() {
    $('.backdrop,.box').animate({
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 300, 'linear', function() {
        $('.backdrop,.box').css('display', 'none');
    });
}​
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use data attributes as selectors http://jsfiddle.net/Q676T/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.lightbox').click( function() {
        var dataTag = $(this).data('tag');
        $('.backdrop')
            .animate({'opacity': '.50'}, 300, 'linear')
            .css('display', 'block');

        $('.box[data-tag='+dataTag+']')
            .animate({'opacity': '1'}, 300, 'linear')
            .css('display', 'block');    
    });

    $('.close, .backdrop').click( function() {
        $('.backdrop, .box')
            .animate({'opacity': '0'}, 300, 'linear', 
                     function(){ $(this).css('display', 'none');})

    });
});

​
```

Comment: Isn't that an HTML5 attribute and not compatible with some browsers?

Comment: I had to make an edit on jsfiddle maybe it didnt go through, I pasted the JavaScript that I modified above and i made both of your boxes class box

Comment: @VictorKilo data is an HTML5 attribute, But it will work as long as your using JQuery because it will act as a shim, You cannot relay on the browser to support retrieval